# Custom entities extraction from texts

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition

What is the right approach for multi-label text information extraction/classification

Having texts that describe a caregiver/patient visit : (made-up example)

> Mr *** visits the clinic on 02/2/2018 complaining about pain in the
> lower back for several days, No pathological findings in the x-ray or
> in the blood tests. I suggest Mr *** 5 resting days.

Now, that text can be even in a paragraph size where the **only** information I care about will be **lower back pain** and **resting days**.  I have 300-400 different labels but the number of labeled samples can be around 1000-1500 (total) . When I label the text I also mark the relevant words that create the "label" ,here it will be ['pain','lower','back'].

When I just use look-up for those words (or the other 300-400 labels) in other texts I manage to label a larger amount of texts but if the words are written in different patterns such as **Ache in the lower back** or "lowerback pain" and I've never added that pattern to the look-up table of "lower back pain" I won't find it.

Due to the fact that I can have large paragraph but the only information I need is just 3-4 words, DL/ML models do not manage to learn with that amount of data and a high number of labels.I am wondering if there is a way to use the lookup table as a feature in the training phase or to try other approaches

Comment: You seems to be describing two problems A) There is a large number of labels B) Each label can have several surfaces.

Comment: What i am trying to understand is - di text classification is the right solution or should i use other methods

Comment: You can get away with something like aho-corasick algorithm.